# Asp.Net if condition says error

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my company want to modify one ASp.net Project,

```
 <% if(Request.QueryString["cert"]!=null)
         { %>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="H&A" ItemStyle-Width="70px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("dia_idealcut_H_A")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            <%  } %>
```

This is html asp code,And |In this page I have url www.domain.com?cert=IGI.
If I get cert I dont want to show this above code how can  I hide If I get url like these..

Parser Error Message: Code blocks are not supported in this context.

this line indicate red color...  **<% if(Request.QueryString["cert"]!=null)**

Can You help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use C# Conditional Operator like this:-

```
 <%# Request.QueryString["cert"] !=null ? Eval("dia_idealcut_H_A") : "" %>
```

**Update:**

If you want to hide the complete column then better to do it in code behind. Add `OnDataBound="myGridView_DataBound"` attribute to your gridview and in code behind hide the column like this:-

```
protected void myGridView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["cert"] == null)
    {
        myGridView.Columns[3].Visible = false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hi Rahul,,It is working.but I don't want display the heading also.I tried your way it shows the same error. <%# Request.QueryString["cert"] !=null ? %><asp:TemplateField HeaderText="H&A" ItemStyle-Width="70px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                               <%#  Eval("dia_idealcut_H_A") %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField><%# : "" %>

Comment: @SelvanKumar - Please check my update. It should work.

Comment: Hi rahul,I have another problem,when I add some values I got some error..(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: @dia_mmshape is not a parameter for procedure sp_tbldiamonds.),,,,,This is the line..(param[21] = new SqlParameter("@dia_mmshape", txtmmSize.Text);
        k = obj.ddlChangeProc("sp_tbldiamonds", param);))

Comment: @SelvanKumar - You are passing `@dia_mmshape` parameter to SP `sp_tbldiamonds` which does not contain such parameter or you may be hitting a wrong SP. Check the version of SP.

Comment: Rahul,tbldiamonds table has dia_mmshape field..In tbldiamonds I added this field(dia_mmshape)..I followed the same procedure before they did..